# Functional complete and xor

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Give a formal proof for the claim that the set $\{xor\}$ is not functional complete.

One possible way is to show that we cannot create the function $\lnot$. I tried to prove it by using induction on the structure of $A$. If $A$ is a formula and $V$ is a model that gives $f$ to all atomic formulas then $V(A) = f$. The base case is $A = p$ and so $V(A) = f$. We assume that it holds for the formulas $B$ and $C$. We have $A = xor(B,C)$ and by using the induction hypothesis and the definition of $xor$ we get $V(A) = f$.

But I want to show that we cannot create the function $\land$ I tried using the same method as before but it doesn't seem to work. What should the induction hypothesis be in this case?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Post's characterization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness#Characterization_of_functional_completeness) of functional completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider an *induction* on the number of *occurrences* of connective in the formula.

*Consider* $\land$

*Basis* : in $p \land q$, when $p$ and $q$ have *different* truth values, then $p \land q$ is *false*.

*Induction step* : let $F_n^{\land}(p,q)$ a formula built with only the literals $p$ and $q$ with $n$ occurrences of $\land$, and assume as *Induction hypo* that it is identically *false*.

If we consider now $F_{n+1}^{\land}(p,q)$ (i.e $F_n^{\land}(p,q) \land p$ or $F_n^{\land}(p,q) \land q$), again it is identically *false*.

*Consider* $xor$ (i.e. $\nLeftrightarrow$)

*Basis* : in $p \nLeftrightarrow q$, when $p$ and $q$ have *different* truth values, then $p \nLeftrightarrow q$ is *true*.

*Induction step* : let $F_n^{\nLeftrightarrow}(p,q)$ a formula built with only the literals $p$ and $q$ with $n$ occurrences of $\nLeftrightarrow $, ans assume as *Induction hypo* that it is **not** identically *false*.

If we consider now $F_{n+1}^{\nLeftrightarrow}(p,q)$ (i.e $F_n^{\nLeftrightarrow}(p,q) \nLeftrightarrow p$ or $F_n^{\land}(p,q) \nLeftrightarrow q$), it can be *true* or *false*, and adding a new literal $p$ (or $q$), the result $F_{n+1}^{\nLeftrightarrow}$ will "flip" according to the value of $p$ (or $q$).

Thus, we have that it is **not** identically *false*.

Comment: But why the only possibilities for $F_{n+1}^{\nLeftrightarrow}(p,q)$ are $F_n^{\nLeftrightarrow}(p,q) \nLeftrightarrow p$ or $F_n^{\land}(p,q) \nLeftrightarrow q$. There may be other possibilities.

Comment: @user91015 - **If** we want to prove that with only the $xor$ connective we are unable to reproduce $\land$, we assume a language with only $xor$; thus, all formulae have only this connective. Then the proof is based on the impossibility of reproducing a formula with only two prop vars $p,q$ "joined" with a combination of $xor$ whatever. THis is the reason way in the induction step I have only two possibility (having fixed $F_n$) : $F_n \land p$ and $F_n \land q$.

Comment: I don't understand what you proved. What about $xor(xor(p,xor(q,q)),p)$ isn't it identically false?

Comment: @user91015 - but the idea of my proof is to start with $xor(p,q)$; of course, I may be wrong ...

Comment: What about $xor(xor(xor(p,q),p),q)$? It is identically false and starts from $xor(p,q)$.

Comment: @user91015 - you are right; you have to find another way to prove it.