# Can $A\cap B$ be represented in terms of the symmetric difference?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Suppose we have a collection of subsets $\mathfrak C$ of $M$ such that

1. $M \in \mathfrak C$
2. $A,B\in \mathfrak C \implies A \Delta B \in \mathfrak C$

I was wondering how this kind of collection of sets is related to an algebra of sets. My hunch is that the two concepts might be the same. Clearly, an algebra of sets satisfies the above two properties. For the reverse direction note that for any $A$ and $B$ in $\mathfrak C,$ 
$$
A^C = M \Delta A,
$$ 
and
$$
A\cup B = (A\Delta B) \Delta (A\cap B).
$$
So the reverse direction is true if and only if $A\cap B$ can be represented in terms of the symmetric difference. Therefore my question:

> Can $A\cap B$ be represented in terms of the symmetric difference? If not, is there a name for a set that is closed under symmetric differences?

---

**Definitions:**

The symmetric difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ is
$$
A\Delta B = A\cup B - (A\cap B).
$$

An algebra of sets on a set $M$ is a collection $\mathfrak A$ of subsets of $M$ such that

1. $M \in \mathfrak A$
2. $A \in \mathfrak A \implies A^C \in \mathfrak A$
3. $A, B \in \mathfrak A \implies A\cup B \in \mathfrak A$

Comment: Simple example which proves non-equivalence: The collection of even-cardinality subsets of {1,2,3,4} is closed under symmetric difference and complements.  But it is not closed under intersections or unions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't, and it's for the same reason that [you cannot express $A \land B$ in terms of $XOR$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778451/functional-complete-and-xor).

More directly in terms of sets: by induction you can prove that no matter which way you combine $A$'s, $B$'s and $XOR$'s, the resulting expression will always denote a set that includes an even number of sets out of the following sets: $A \cap B$, $A \cap B^C$,$A^C \cap B$,and $A^C \cap B^C$.

Or in terms of the Venn diagram for $A$ and $B$: any such expression will pick out an even number of the $4$ regions of the Venn diagram for $A$ and $B$, while $A \cap B$ is just $1$ of those.